# --ipcpath is incorrect

Tags: go-ethereum, ipc

So I'm trying to setup my private node environment, I've got a `startnode.sh` script which looks like this:

```
  geth --networkid 4224 --mine --minerthreads 2 --datadir "." --nodiscover --rpc --rpcport "8545" --port "30303" --rpccorsdomain "*" --nat "any" --rpcapi eth,web3,personal, net --unlock 0 --password ./password.sec --ipcpath "~/.ethereum/geth.ipc"
```

When I try to run the script, I can see that all other variables are correct except my ipc path, which is for some reason always being set to the local repository where I execute the script:

`INFO [03-15|22:32:27] IPC endpoint opened url=/home/lovro/ChainSkills/private/geth.ipc`

Comment: Could it have something to do with the rights of the bash script ?

Comment: if you are going to connect to a node via ipc use `geth attach ipc:/path/to/geth.ipc` , you don't have to specify any other variables as it will connect to a node previously started and the parameters will be those that the node has set itself on startup

Comment: Try giving an absolute path in the IPC path